# Will replacing stock fan ban my console?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

If I replace the stock fan in my Xbox 360 with something quieter, would my console be flagged as 'modded' and hence ban my console, or live account?

Answer (score 5):

This may void your warranty (for repairs), but will not be detected as a 'mod'.

Mods are considered to be any action or item that circumvents the built-in security measures of the console.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of this happening to some people.  Apparently, the fan causes a greater (or perhaps fluctuating) voltage drop which the console detects and reports back to Microsoft.  This can apparently earn you a ban, possibly because mods can cause the same sort of effect.

Instead of replacing your existing fan, can you use an externally powered or USB fan to blow extra air in?  I can't remember if the 360's fan is temperature sensing but that might cause it to run slower.

Comment: Wow - that's horrible.